# Codeigniter 2.1, PHP - working with $_GET

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I have this kind of url:

> ..?brend=Sony&id=1

where brend itself is variable and it can take different values. I was wondering how can I get value of this part (not the part after brend, the value of the brend itself)?

Comment: How you should identify that `brend` variable? If it's the only 'non-id' key of `$_GET` array, it's more-o-less simple, but in other cases, not so... Well, you can use another variable, with fixed name, that will store the name of this variable variable (like `label=brend&brend=Sony&id=1`) - but honestly speaking, that's messy. )

Comment: BTW, why it's `brend`, not `brand`? )

Comment: I am working in Serbia and brand here is spelled brend :D. I need to get value before Sony, because this part can take multiple values, depending on the need. So it can be **category=Sony** or **name=Sony** or **type=Sony**. I need to determinate which one it is.

Comment: So it's actually a `Sony` word that is a variable name probably? ) Anyway, just get an array of GET variables, then look for a key which value is 'Sony' (with [array_search](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php), for example).

Comment: Or, if `Sony` is also variable, just extract all the $_GET keys, then search them for a key not equal to `id`.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Input class](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/input.html):

```
$id = $this->input->get('id', true);
```

Answer (score 0):

While you can use the framework's features, using CodeIgniter doesn't prevent you from just using `$_GET['brend'];`

Comment: From what I know, CI empties the `$_GET` array and stores it for `$this->input->get()`

Comment: @BurningtheCodeigniter -_______________-

Answer (score 0):

simple...

```
$brend_value = $_GET['brend'];
```

or it can be

```
$brend_value = $this->input->GET['brend'];
```